# Android: how do I determine the screen coordinates of a long press which opens a Context Menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, coordinates

My app's main View displays a graphical Canvas. The onCreate method of the main Activity contains the command `registerForContextMenu(mapview);` so when the user does a long press on this View a context menu is opened whose contents are defined in the Activity's `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)` method.

I would like to vary the menu's contents according to the location of the press, but I can't see how to find out that location. None of the arguments supplied to onCreateContextMenu seem to supply that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky one and just a stab in the dark I'm afraid...

You don't mention what your 'main View' class is but if it is a 'native' android one then derive your own extending the one you're currently using.

Give your class public X and Y data members, e.g.,...

```
public int lastKnownX; // Might be float types - can't remember
public int lastKnownY;
```

Also in your class, override `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` and check the `MotionEvent` to see if it is an `ACTION_DOWN` event - if it is, store the X and Y co-ordinates in `lastKnownX` and `lastKnownY`. - ignore any other events and make sure you ALWAYS return false regardless of the motion action (to make the process transparent).

My theory is that when a long click/press is interpreted, your last known `ACTION_DOWN` co-ordinates will be those of where that long click started and, because they're accessible by your activity (you defined them as public), the `onCreateContextMenu()` method will be able to use them.

On the other hand I might be way off but that's how I'd approach the problem. Worth a try. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've done what you suggested (with one modification ... I already have a MyGestureDetector class which extends SimpleOnGestureListener; this contains an `onDown(MotionEvent e)` method which is called at the beginning of any press, so I put the code to get the coordinates from `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` there.) This seems to do the job fine.

Comment: @prepbgg: OK that's great, glad my suggestion was useful.